# Razor syntax issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Looked at examples so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here.
The else condition isn't working and it's telling me there is no closing } on the foreach command

```
<table class="rssTable">
    @foreach (var item in PAL.Intranet.Models.RSSReader.GetRSSFeed("http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/rss/featurednews.xml"))
    {
        <tr>
            @if (rssCount % 2 != 0)
            {
                <td class="rssTableOdd">
            }
            else
            {
                <td class="rssTableEven">
            }
                <a href="@item.Link" target="_blank">@Html.Encode(item.Title.Replace("Medical News Today: ", ""))</a><br />
                @Html.Raw(item.Description)
            </td>
        </tr>
        rssCount++;

        if (rssCount.Equals(5))
        {
            rssCount = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I think removing the `@` in front of the first if statement should fix your issues.  Also, you do not need to call Html.Encode on the title as the razor `@` html helper automatically does this for you.  On the description, you can update that to be `@Html.Raw(item.Description)`.  Its a little cleaner and accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: @Tommy didn't work. Syntax becomes regular text and is added as regular text on the page.

Comment: Is this the entire view or are we missing some of it?

Comment: @DavidG there are tables prior to the code but this is the only section that has code other than html

Comment: You can always put `@:` in front of the bits of html it's finding confusing. I'm fairly sure I've had to do this with `<td>` elements before. `@:` means "the rest of this line is markup and not code". Somewhat similar to `Html.Raw()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is coming down to having the start of a `<td>` tag in your if/else columns.  Using Resharper, I noticed that I had to place an `@` in front of the else condition as well once I removed the autocoded `</td>` at the end of each of the starting `<td>` tags.

This modification should work (firing up a test solution now).

```
        @if (rssCount % 2 != 0)
        {
            <td class="rssTableOdd">
        }
        @else
        {
            <td class="rssTableEven">
        }
```

Another way to make the view parser happier is to simply declare a variable and use that as the class:

```
@{var cssClass = "rssTableEven";}
    @foreach (var item in PAL.Intranet.Models.RSSReader.GetRSSFeed("http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/rss/featurednews.xml"))
    {
        <tr>
            @if (rssCount % 2 != 0)
            {
                cssClass = "rssTableOdd";
            }
            else
            {
                cssClass = "rssTableEven";
            }
<td class="@cssClass">stuff</td>
</tr>
```

Or a final (cleaner?) way would be to put that logic directly into the `<td class=>` tag.

```
<td class="@(rssCount % 2 == 0 ? "rssTableEven" : "rssTableOdd")"></td>
```

This should clean up a lot of your view logic.

Answer (score 2):

A simple rewrite of your `if` logic into an inline conditional will prevent the Razor engine being confused with your particular setup (My conditional still confuses StackOverflow's code engine though :):

```
@foreach (var item in PAL.Intranet.Models.RSSReader.GetRSSFeed("http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/rss/featurednews.xml"))
{
    <tr>
        <td class="@(rssCount % 2 != 0 ? "rssTableOdd" : "rssTableEven")">
            <a href="@item.Link" target="_blank">@Html.Encode(item.Title.Replace("Medical News Today: ", ""))</a><br />
            @Html.Raw(item.Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
    rssCount++;

    if (rssCount.Equals(5))
    {
        rssCount = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```